# Why does this code print infinite numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, iterable

In this code, why when I put a string "6" instead of 6 in x1 = Chain ("6"), it prints an infinite number in execution?

```
class Chain:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.counter = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if self.counter != self.n:
            self.counter += 1
        else:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.counter

    def __iter__(self):
        return self


x1 = Chain("6")

for i in x1:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Because the int `self.counter` is never equal to the string "6". Ints are not equal to strings.

Comment: Are you pasing 6 as a string? Should be a int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `x1 = Chain("6")` sets `self.n = "6"`, which is a string.  In the object you have `counter` as an integer.  An integer can never be equal to a string, so your `self.counter != self.n` always returns `True` and the `else` block is never entered.

If I were you, I'd modify your `__init__` to:

```py
def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = int(n)
        self.counter = 0
```